# RTL support on ImageButton with autoMirror for src drawable

Tags: android, right-to-left

When creating an ImageButton with `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` and `android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send"`, adding `android:autoMirror="true"` does not have any descernable affect. Is there any way to easily support Right-To-Left (RTL) image mirroring on `ImageButtons`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Make an XML drawable and set `android:autoMirrored="true"`. This value is ignored before API 19.

`res/drawable/icon_auto_mirrored.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:autoMirrored="true"/>
```

Now use `android:src="@drawable/icon_auto_mirrored` in your layout.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. It worked like a charm. It's annoying to have to have an extra file for each image that needs to be auto-mirrored, but at least there is a way.

Comment: @StevenCVAL, thanks for a simple and effective solution, but in my case it doesn't work. The referred image is `"@android:drawable/ic_media_ff"`. Maybe it deals to speciality of the image, doesn't it?

Comment: @SkyKelsey I wrote a [library](https://github.com/qiantao94/AndroidAutoRtlImage), no need an extra file, use it directly in layout xml file.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out if I need to do this again.

Answer (score 9):

1. Add `rotationY` to the `ImageView` :

   < ImageView ...  android:rotationY="@integer/rtl_mirror_flip"
2. Declare `rtl_mirror_flip` as 0 (for ltr), or 180 (for rtl ) :

   < integer name="rtl_mirror_flip">0< /integer>
   or
   < integer name="rtl_mirror_flip">180< /integer>

Comment: Cool hack! Can really save a lot of space and redundant duplication of image resources. Thanks)